# How do I get rid of this blue line? (Vscode R)

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know how to get rid of this blue line? It pops up all the time.

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW42V.png)]

I'm working in Visual Studio Code 1.73.

I have tried all of the code below:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "progressBar.background": "#fff0",
        "editorError.foreground": "#00000000",
        "editorWarning.foreground": "#00000000",
        "editorInfo.foreground": "#00000000",
        "diffEditor.removedLineBackground": "#00000000"
    },
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast",
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "r.alwaysUseActiveTerminal": true,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "r.bracketedPaste": true,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "editor.hover.sticky": false,
    "editor.parameterHints.enabled": false,
    "editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false,
    "css.validate": false,
    "editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
    "editor.wordWrapColumn": 160
```

Which i found and got from Stack Overflow, but sadly this one sticks.

Comment: do you have a tooltip when you hover over the blue line? Disable your extensions and see if it goes away, then enable them one by one

Comment: Does it appear under all comments that you create using `#`? Or only in particular scenarios?

Comment: Every scanerio except ```#```